# select element from navbar for selenium web driver chrome

Tags: selenium-webdriver

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGLCf.png)I have below code

```
<a class="mynavlink" href="#"><i class="glyphicon icon-list"></i> Accounts</a>
<ul style="list-style-type: none;z-index:100;">
<li><a class="mynavlink" href="/user"><i class="glyphicon icon-user"></i> Users</a></li>                  
<li><a class="mynavlink" href="/groups"><i class="glyphicon icon-group"></i> Groups</a></li>                
<li><a class="mynavlink" href="/user/profile"><i class="glyphicon icon-user"></i> My Profile</a></li> 
</ul>
```

There is mynavlink is a navbar class.
Account is a heading and three option is opened **User,Group,Myprofile** after hovering the cursor on Account.

I want to click on user. Therefore I want to find exact element to click on User.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should perform first mouseover on `Accounts` link then go to click on menu option as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);

WebElement accounts = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.partialLinkText("Accounts")));
builder.mouse.mouseMove(((Locatable)accounts).coordinates); //it will perform mouse over on Accounts link      

WebElement users = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.partialLinkText("Users"));
users.click(); //It will click on users link
```

Hope it helps...:)

Comment: Y not to use ClickandHold()?

Comment: @Aishu OP wants mouse over while `clickAndHold()` uses for Clicks (without releasing) at the current mouse location...:)

Comment: yes, but after ClickandHold() we can use movetoElement() and use the release()

Comment: Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.clickAndHold(webelement).build().perform();
    actions.MoveToElement(element).Release();

Comment: @Aishu Yeah you can use it as an other option..:)

Comment: :)...I feel this is simple...But ur answer is also an work around

Comment: @Aishu..yeah but some time `clickAndHold` does not work around..that's why I consider separate mouse over and click...thanks..:)

Comment: WebElement accounts = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.partialLinkText("Accounts")));
   WebElement users = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.partialLinkText("Users")));
   Actions action = new Actions(driver);
   action.clickAndHold(accounts).build().perform(); 
   action.moveToElement(users).release();
   users.click();

Comment: Starting ChromeDriver 2.20.353124 (035346203162d32c80f1dce587c8154a1efa0c3b) on port 7343
Only local connections are allowed.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"a.mynavlink[href*=user]"}
  (Session info: chrome=49.0.2623.110)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.20.353124 (035346203162d32c80f1dce587c8154a1efa0c3b),platform=Linux 3.19.0-
 at create.main(create.java:25)
this error found

Comment: @ShivajiGhadge what do you want?? I didn't understand why are you shareing this??

Comment: Sorry my mistake It does not find out element. I will check other way to select element .

Answer (score 0):

Add id in `li` and then call this script with appropriate timeout

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout).until(
           lambda x: x.find_elements_by_css_id('#user'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some css selectors:

```css
ul a[href*=user]
a.mynavlink[href*=user]
ul a[href='/user']
a.mynavlink[href='/user']
```

For more selectors please see [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: i edited the one with ul, added a dot by mistake. all of them are valid selectors.Please try again.

Comment: i tried driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.mynavlink[href*=user]")).click();

Comment: What is the error? Have you also did a hover/click on the Account before?